# Is $\int_a^{\infty}(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a})\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{\frac{-(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$ increasing in $\sigma$?

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

I have the following integral which is similar to the conditional expectation of the square root of a truncated normal. To be exact I have

$$I(\sigma):=\int_a^{\infty}(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a})\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{\frac{-(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$$

Where $0<a<m$. My question is this an increasing function of $\sigma$? I suspect is but I am having the most difficult time showing it formally. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\begin{align*}\frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma}\left(\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right) &= \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}+\frac{1}{\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\cdot\frac{(x-m)^2}{\sigma^3}\right) \\ &= \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma^4}e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\left((x-m)^2-\sigma^2\right),\end{align*}$$ which is absolutely integrable in $x$ over $[a,\infty)$ since $\sqrt{x}e^{-x^2}x^2 = x^{\frac{5}{2}}e^{-x^2}$ is integrable over $[0,\infty)$. Thus, by the dominated convergence theorem, $$\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} I'(\sigma) = \int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma^4}e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\left((x-m)^2-\sigma^2\right) \dif x,$$ which is not guaranteed to be positive, due to the $(x-m)^2-\sigma^2$ term. It follows that this integral is *not* increasing in $\sigma$. (Indeed, we can verify numerically that taking e.g. $a = 1$ and $m = 5$ appears to give $I'(3) \approx -0.00903$.)